# Zoom a web page without increasing scrollbar width? or specify scrollbar width?

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar, zooming

I have a website where there is a **fixed-size, floating menu**.

The **menu does not change size when the browser is zoomed** (well, it's shrunk back to the original size when zoomed).

The point is **to be able to browser-zoom in on a big photograph while keeping a small navigational menu** on top of everything.

The problem is that when one zooms in to look at details of the photograph (cmd+), **the scrollbars get huge and start to take over the screen visually**.

Is there any way to **specify the size of the scrollbars** so that they will still appear but not get so big?

Answer (score 1):

The scroll bars **vary** throughout the different browsers and versions.

In older versions of IE this is might be a problem, but in the most recent version of Chrome it doesn't seem to be.

But as for keeping the small navigational menu, use **percents** to describe the CSS value of the menu so it takes up **a defined portion** of the page.